# Zendramework 2 ClassMethod Hydrator

Tags: zend-framework2, class-method

I have underscore fields in my table like display_name I use ClassMethod hydrator to convert underscore to camel case but It doesn't work , (email property works but displayName doesn't work) this is my code :

```
class UserEntity 
{

protected $email;
protected $displayName;


public function getDisplayName()
{
    return $this->displayName;
}

public function setDisplayName($displayName)
{
    $this->displayName = $displayName;
    return $this;
}

public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}

public function setEmail($email)
{
    $this->email = $email;
}

}

$dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
$UserEntity = new \UserManagement\Model\UserEntity;
$hydrator = new \Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods;
$resultSet = new \Zend\Db\ResultSet\HydratingResultSet($hydrator,$UserEntity);
$tableGateway = new \Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway('user',$dbAdapter,null,$resultSet);
$table = new \UserManagement\Model\UserTable($tableGateway);
```

Comment: please somebody help me

Comment: If the hydrator does not work the way you want you can make one yourself, just implement `Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\HydratorInterface` I had som trouble with ClassMethod because my entities extends from an abstract entity and had several class in parent that I don't want to be hydrated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure all of your database fields have data ?
Maybe they are empty and simply it doesn't return any valud

Comment: Yes , you're right , database didn't have any value :D

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing your own hydrator, you could create a new Naming Strategy and assign it to the hydrator.  The ClassMethods hydrator, by default, uses the Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\NamingStrategy\UnderscoreNamingStrategy.  You could examine the code in the strategy, and make the appropriate changes, creating your own custom naming strategy. Make sure you also create an interface to match it.

You would then need to remove the UnderscoreNamingStrategy, and add your own custom one as follows:

```
$hydrator = new ClassMethods();
$hydrator->removeNamingStrategy('UnderscoreNamingStrategy');
$hydrator->addStrategy('CustomStrategy', 'CustomStrategyInterface');
```